# Make a list View row selected

Tags: android, android-listview, android-dialog

I have an `AlertDialog` which contains a `ListView`. The `ListView` is populated via a customCursor adapter. Everything works fine except that I am unable to set a particular row as selected(highlighted with the blue color in Holo theme) inside the `ListView`.

```
public AlertDialog m_accountsDialog;

private AlertDialog createAccountSwitcherDialog2()
{
    Cursor listCursor = getDb().getAllListEntries();
    if(listCursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        //Prepare the dialog box
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.strAccounts);

        ListView listView = new ListView(this);
        listView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        listView.setAdapter(new AccountsAdapter(this,this,m_ActiveId, listCursor));
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, final long rowId)
            {
                m_accountsDialog.dismiss();
                if(m_ActiveId != (int) rowId)
                {
                    //Do some stuff on click
                }
            }
        });
        builder.setView(listView);
        builder.setPositiveButton(...);
        builder.setNegativeButton(...);

        m_accountsDialog = builder.create();
        m_accountsDialog.setOnShowListener(...);
        m_accountsDialog.show();
    }

    return m_accountsDialog;

}
```

Here is the adapter used to populate the listView that is inside the alert Dialog.

```
public class AccountsAdapter extends CursorAdapter
{
    private Context  m_context; /**<Context to which we're bound*/
    private Activity m_activity;
    private boolean  m_isTabletDevice;
    private int      m_ActiveId; // not used now. Can this be used to highlight the row?

   public AccountsAdapter(Context context,Activity activity,int activeId, Cursor cursor)
   {
       super(context, cursor);
       m_context = context;
       m_activity = activity;
       m_isTabletDevice          = isTabletDevice(context);
       m_ActiveId           = activeId;
   }


   @Override
   public void bindView(View rowView,final Context context, Cursor cursor)
   {
       if(rowView == null)
       {
           rowView = newView(context,cursor,null);
       }
       TextView tv = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.accountName);
       tv.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ProfileDatabase.COLUMN_PROFILENAME)));

      ImageButton editAccountImageButton = (ImageButton) rowView.findViewById(R.id.accountEdit);
           editAccountImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {               
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0)
             {
                 Integer activeId = (Integer)arg0.getTag();
                 if(m_activity instanceof MainActivity)
                 {
                     ((MyActivity)m_activity).m_accountsDialog.dismiss();
                     ((MyActivity)m_activity).startEditAccountsActivity(activeId);
                 }

             }
           });
          int accountId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ProfileDatabase.COLUMN_ACCOUNT_ID));
          editAccountImageButton.setTag(profileId);
          editAccountImageButton.setFocusable(false);
   }

   @Override
   public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent)
   {
       //create and return a rowView
   }
}
```

The custom row of my list view.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/accountEdit" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/option_selector"
    android:src="@drawable/edit_account_button" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/accountName" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/accountEdit"
    android:bufferType="spannable"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
```

I tried,

```
listView.setItemChecked(position, true);
listView.setSelection(position);
```

in the function which creates the alert dialog but it did not work.
The other option I have is to manually set a background color to the row View in my adapter, which of course is not advisable as the theme may change from device to device.

Thanks in advance and sorry for a lengthy post.

Answer (score 1):

Create `selector_row.xml` in drawable folder as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@color/Highlight_color" android:state_pressed="true"/>
</selector>
```

and set it as background resource for your custom row.

Comment: I don't think highlight_color is a defined constant. It is throwing up an error with @android:color/Highlight_color

Comment: Highlight color should be defined by you in color.xml as          <color name="Highlight_color">#51ffffff</color>

Comment: I mentioned in the question that i don't want to hard code the values. I want a particular row to be focussed whenever i show the dialog and the color should be same as the current theme's focused color. I just want to make listview.setItemSelected(pos,true); to work

Comment: Have you tried this?.  this highlight color is white color with opacity 51%. So what ever be the row color. Highligted row will be having same color as previous with some white color effect. You may increase opacity value so it will be more transparent.